# Why is there a trailing "D" of my println!() output?

Tags: macos, rust, terminal, stty

I am following this [reference](https://www.ralfj.de/projects/rust-101/part03.html) to implement a simple program which calculates the minimum number of inputs:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io;

fn read_vec() -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut vec: Vec<i32> = Vec::<i32>::new();

    let stdin = io::stdin();
    println!("Enter a list of numbers, one per line. End with Ctrl-D (Linux) or Ctrl-Z (Windows).");
    
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        match line.trim().parse::<i32>()  {
            Ok(num) => vec.push(num),
            Err(_) => println!("What did I say about numbers?"),
        }
    }

    vec
}

pub enum SomethingOrNothing<T> {
    Something(T),
    Nothing,
}

pub use self::SomethingOrNothing::*;

type NumberOrNothing = SomethingOrNothing<i32>;

pub trait Minimum: Copy {
    fn min(self, b: Self) -> Self;
}

pub fn vec_min<T: Minimum>(v: Vec<T>) -> SomethingOrNothing<T> {
    let mut min = Nothing;
    for e in v {
        min = match min {
            Something(t) => Something(e.min(t)),
            Nothing => Something(e),
        }
    }
    min
}

impl Minimum for i32 {
    fn min (self, b: Self) -> Self {
        if self < b {self} else {b}
    }
}

impl NumberOrNothing {
    pub fn print(self) {
        match self {
            Nothing => println!("The number is: <nothing>"),
            Something(n) => println!("{}", n),
        };
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec = read_vec();
    let min = vec_min(vec);
    min.print();
}
```

Build an run the program:

```
Enter a list of numbers, one per line. End with Ctrl-D (Linux) or Ctrl-Z (Windows).
100
8
200
8D
```

We can see there is a trailing "`D`" after the minimum number: `8`. But if I changed the output from:

```
Something(n) => println!("{}", n),
```

to:

```
Something(n) => println!("The number is: {}", n),
```

The output seems normal:

```
Enter a list of numbers, one per line. End with Ctrl-D (Linux) or Ctrl-Z (Windows).
100
8
200
The number is: 8
```

I guess the issue is related to stdout buffer, but can't figure out why. Anyone can give some clues?

P.S., I can reproduce this issue on `macOS`(`zsh`) and `OmniOS` (`bash`), but can't reproduce on `Linux`(`bash`).

Comment: I don't reproduce your observation

Comment: Could be your terminal displaying it when you hit `Ctrl-D` to conclude?

Comment: @DenysSéguret I can reproduce it on both macOS and OmniOS.

Comment: @Jmb It seems not.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recreate this on macOS using iTerm (tested with zsh and bash).  It looks like the problem is related to the the terminal echoing signal control commands:

- https://linux.m2osw.com/remove-ctrl-C-from-being-printed-in-console
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558694/why-do-terminals-sometimes-echo-special-characters-like-c

So to stop this, you'll want to turn off `echoctl`

The easiest way to see what's happening is to hit `Crtl-D` while still on a line with a number:

```
Enter a list of numbers, one per line. End with Ctrl-D (Linux) or Ctrl-Z (Windows).
1
2
3
4^D
```

What's happening in your case is: you're on an empty line and hit `Ctrol-D`, the terminal echos `^D` to the line and then moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line, then your programs output overwrites the `^D`.  So, if you output a single digit number, the `^` is overwritten but the `D` remains (as in your example).  When you output more characters the `^` and the `D` are overwritten.

Here's a demonstration where the `D` is overwritten:

```
Enter a list of numbers, one per line. End with Ctrl-D (Linux) or Ctrl-Z (Windows).
100
200
300
100
```